# Subtract value in one cell until it reaches zero before subtracting value from another

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-macros

B9 `=IF(H6,C6,0)-f9`
C9 `=$A$2-E6`
D9 =(NEED HELP)

Is there a formula I can put in D9 OR maybe just add to B9 and C9 (still need the above formulas) that will deduct B9 value until it reaches zero BEFORE deducting from C9 when I enter amount in F9?

Example:

B9 has 150 based on the above formula
C9 has 200 based on the above formula
D9 is the total of B9&C9 350 (This column may not be necessary)
F9 is where I would put in a number so say I put in 175. B9 should now say 0 and C9 should now say 175.

Answer (score 2):

It's basic math:

```
B9 +C9 -F9 =175
150+200-175=175
```

Just add another column.  However you cannot put the result in B9.

That is called a **circular reference**, which is the same idea as saying:

> "I am one year older than you, and you are one year older than me."

You can, however, use one of mpore additional cells/columns, to display your result, like `G9`, and **hide** any columns that you don't want to display.

[image: img]

Comment: Formulas or functions do not "move" values or otherwise change other cells. Technically speaking, you *could* write a VBA subroutine that could automate copy-pasting the value elsewhere but, even without knowing what you're actually trying to accomplish, I can guarantee that is not a good way to do "whatever it is" you need to do, and is not something that accounting of **any* kind normally requires in Excel.  I think you need to take a couple steps back and explain the bigger picture of what you need to do. Some sort of inventory accounting  perhaps? Discuss the problem, not your solution.

Comment: B9 is the amount that I transferred into this year from the previous and is only transferred in when I add a date in column H. C9 is the amount that I get every year minus E6. When I enter an amount into F9, I need to have the B9 deducted first until it reaches 0 before it deducting C9. If I have to have extra columns or extra row that "move" or show that it lessens before the next, that's fine. The above formula you have in H9 adds up both values, I would like to have it show C9 value (200) and then if I type the value making B9 0 then this number lessens. Is that possible?